# Cakephp Multiple Checkboxes in a row not showing values

Tags: cakephp

`$this->Form->checkbox('username', array('value' => 'basssr', 'style' => 'float: left; display: inline'));`
this code only show check box not values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <div style="float:left;">
 <?php
 echo $this->Form->input('username', array('type' => 'checkbox','value' => 'basssr', 'style' => 'float: left; display: inline'));
 ?>
 </div>
```

this code put it 2 times This will shows checkboxes in horizontal.

Comment: i want multiple checkbox in a single row this code shows all checkbox in verticle